# Get dictionary element in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a dictionary and I need to get the element from the dictionary by key. However, the key needs to be set as tf.placeholder and get the value after. For example, I want

```
dict={'a':10,'b':20} 
key=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1]). 
result=dict[key]
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(result, {key:'a'})
```

but it says:

```
KeyError:<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>
```

Can anyone help me get the value from the dictionary but provide the key in feed_dict?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common confusion with TF. While everything looks like python code, what is actually happening is that TF is building a graph of operations and then executes it outside of the python interpreter context. This means that you cannot access python objects from inside the graph. And as far as I know TensorFlow does not support string indexing in its tensors. So what you are doing will not work. The closest you can do is use numeric indexes.

```
data = tf.constant([10, 20]) 
key = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1]). 
result = data[key]
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(result, {key: 1})
# result should now contain 20
```

Comment: Thanks Mad!  What if my dictionary is dict={'a':loss1,'b':loss2} and loss1,2 are tensors? I want to evaluate loss1 or loss2 based on the tf.placeholder is 'a' or 'b'.

Comment: Just use numeric indexing. losses = [loss1, loss2] and pass 0 or 1 to the feed dict. Also, don't call your variable `dict` it clashes with the dict data type and you can get some very unpleasant bugs that way.

Comment: If you want it to be friendly, map your human readable keys to numbers in a separate dict.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this worked for me based on Mad's solution:

```
dict={'a':10,'b':20} 
data = tf.convert_to_tensor(dict.values())
key = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=None) 
result = tf.gather(data, key)
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(result, {key: [0,1,0]})
```